# How do I add to an ArrayList from one class, when the ArrayList and constructors/getters are stored 2 other classes

Tags: java, class, arraylist, methods

I have 3 classes, `Session`, `Employee`, and `Employees`. The `Employee` class has the constructors and getters, the `Employees` class has the `ArrayList`, and I'm trying to add to that `ArrayList` within the `Session` class.

```java
public class Employee {
    public Employee(String name, String email){
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Employees {
    private ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    public Employees(){
        employees.add(new Employee("John Smith", "johnsmith@email.com"));
    }

    public void addEmpNew (Employee empNew){
        employees.add(empNew);
    }
}
```

```java
public class Session {
    private void addEmployee(){
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        String addEmpName = In.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Email: ");
        String addEmpEmail = In.nextLine();

        Employees v1 = new Employees();
        v1.addEmpNew(new Employee(addEmpName, addEmpEmail));
    }
}
```

But when I run it and put in the new employee and use a `viewEmployees()` method that shows all employees, It doesn't show the new one I added in, only showing the john smith one I pre-wrote in. I have a suspicion there may be something wrong with the `addEmpNew` method but I'm not sure.

Comment: "when I run it", how exactly do you do that?

Comment: Could you post your `viewEmployees` implementation and also show us how you're calling it?

Comment: Maybe to get you closer to the problem, you could also try to print the content of `addEmpName` and `addEmpEmail`, so you know that the user input actually made it's way to your variables :) Beside that, without knowing how you execute it and what the implementation of viewEmployees is, it will be hard for us to spot the issue.

Also, you might want to make yourself comfortable with the concept of debugging the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an instance of Employees (called v1) within the `addEmployee` method. After the `addEmployee` method completes, all of the variables inside the method are gone (ready to be garbage collected).

If you are expecting to only have one instance of the Employees, consider making it a global variable.

```
public class Session {
    private final Employees v1 = new Employees();

    private void addEmployee(){
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        String addEmpName = In.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Email: ");
        String addEmpEmail = In.nextLine();

        v1.addEmpNew(new Employee(addEmpName, addEmpEmail));
    }

    private void printEmployees(){
        // you will have to implement the toString method in Employees class
        System.out.print("Employees: " + v1.toString());
    }
}
```